# Node express-validation optional option not working

Tags: node.js, validation, express

I'm trying to run this validation, but for some reason it validates the parameter even if I set optional to true. Is there anyone that knows what I'm doing wrong?

```
var schema = {
  "title": {
    in: "body",
    optional: true,
    isLength: {
      options: [{ min: 1, max: 128 }],
      errorMessage: 'Title must be between 1 and 128 characters'
    }
  }
}
req.check(schema)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Straight from the [docs](https://github.com/ctavan/express-validator#optional-input) it says:

> You can use the optional() method to skip validation. By default, it only skips validation if the key does not exist on the request object. If you want to skip validation based on the property being falsy (null, undefined, etc), you can pass in { checkFalsy: true }.

I assume in your case, the title key is present in the request body but the value is a blank string. So that checkFalsy value won't work. At least it never did for me. To make the validation optional you can create a custom validator and use it in your schema:

```js
this.app = express();

this.app.use(expressValidator({
  customValidators: {
    isLengthOptional: (str, options) => {
      // make it optional
      if (str === undefined || str === '') {
        return true;
      }
      const min = options.min || 0;
      const max = options.max;
      const surrogatePairs = str.match(/[\uD800-\uDBFF][\uDC00-\uDFFF]/g) || [];
      const len = str.length - surrogatePairs.length;
      return len >= min && (typeof max === 'undefined' || len <= max);
    }
  }
});
var schema = {
  "title": {
    in: "body",
    optional: true,
    isLengthOptional: {
      options: [{ min: 1, max: 128 }],
      errorMessage: 'Title must be between 1 and 128 characters'
    }
  }
}
req.check(schema)
```

Comment: Wow, that's quite nice. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The optional flag in schema means that the field could be omitted, in case it presents it must follow the rule provided.

In your example, this would be considered valid since the "title" is omitted.

```
{
  "body": {}
}
```

Meanwhile, this would be invalid since the "title" is present but not follow the rule

```
{
  "body": {
    "title": null
  }
}
```

This is just my assumption based on what you posted, if you provided more information it would be much easier to debug. Something like:
which request did you send to your app?
what is the response you get from that request?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I needed a parameter to be optional and accept integer values if sent.
With `checkSchema`, the following works properly:

```
    checkSchema({
        boxId: {
            optional: { 
                options: {
                    checkFalsy: true,
                },
            },
            in: ['body'],
            errorMessage: 'invalid boxId',
            isInt: true
        },
        // ...
    })
```

Bear in mind that checkFalsy accepts `0`, `""`, `false` and `null` as values that mean the property is optional. I tried to get this to work with `checkNull` (so only `null` would be used to represent that the property is optional), but it didn't work.

Using express-validator 6.10.1 here.